# Powering arduino with battery

Tags: arduino-uno, battery

I haven't tried so don't know if it works or not. So I got a 6v battery AA, is it possible to run my arduino uno which already got a code in it if I plug + pin to vin and - to GND? Without its USB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get a 5 battery holder and put 5 alkaline batteries into it. (5 battery holders are sometimes used to provide 6 volts from ni-cat or NiMh batteries, which provide ≈1.2V.

5 alkaline AA batteries would give you ≈7.5V, which gives you more "wiggle room" for the voltage regulator.

### EDIT:

As Gerben pointed out in their comment, 5 AA batteries will drop below the minium voltage input to the Arduino's voltage regulator well before they are depleted. A 6 battery holder would let you use more of the total battery capacity. (At the cost of wasting the excess voltage as heat.)

Comment: With only 5 batteries, the voltage will drop below 6V when the individual batteries reach 1.2V. This will use, at best, only 66% of the capacity of an AA battery. I'd suggest a 6 AA battery holder.

Answer (score 1):

The UNO recommends at least 7 Volts on the Vin. 6 Volt is the absolute minimum. As the AA batteries drain, the voltage will be below this 6 Volts very quickly.

I tend to use a 3xAA battery holder, giving around 4.5Volt, and connect that straight to the Vcc pin (bypassing the voltage regulator). This works just fine in most cases.

Comment: Sorry im quite new to this, but where is the vcc pin?

Comment: Is it the one in the ISCP?

Comment: Because my idea is that i want to use both the 3.3v and 5v pins, without using adapter or the usb cable

Comment: That is a very bad idea. You should never feed unregulated power into the VCC pin.

Comment: Eh, feeding battery power to VCC is only a moderately poor idea, and not always even that bad.

Comment: I meant the 5v pin.

Answer (score 0):

Go and buy some 9v Duracell battery and use it . Put the plus in Vin and the negative in gnd  .
Also i noticed that you are a newbie to arduino  so  be aware.
5v pin in arduino it's an output voltage.
3.3 v also output voltage.
Vin is the vcc is An electronics designation that refers to voltage from a power supply connected to the "collector" terminal of a bipolar transistor. In an NPN bipolar (BJT) transistor, it would be +Vcc, while in a PNP transistor, it would be -Vcc.
Gnd mean ground .
Read this please.
https://www.pcmag.com/encyclopedia/term/53705/vcc